# What are the rules for using out keyword in generics type without getting a compilation error

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, covariant

In Kotlin i am learning about covariant(a subtype can be used in place of a super type).
They wrote there something like a rule. but it seems wrong for me. It is written:

> You can’t, however, use out if the class has function parameters or var
> properties of that generic type.

But i think that the word **or** should be replaced with the word **and**, because in situation when a class has a function that "gets" the type as a parameter, if the property of the generic type is a **val** and not **var**, and damage can't be done, because any assignment isn't possible to val property.
Am i right or what is written in the book is correct and i'm missing something?

Edit:
I just realized (according to some post i saw in this forum) that **the only situation** that a parameter can be a problem although property is declared as val, is in case we have a container of type T, let's say List then it may be a problem if we try to add to the *List*, but if we don't have a container i can't see situation when getting a parameter type can make trouble while property is val. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

The `out` keyword is for *covariance*, not *contravariance*.

Here's a basic example of the trouble caused in an imaginary class where covariance is allowed for the `var` property type:

```
class Container<out T>(var item: T)

val intContainer = Container<Int>(1)
val numberContainer: Container<Number> = intContainer // cast is allowed for covariant type
numberContainer.item = 5f // allowed if item is a var
val intValue = intContainer.item // Float value is cast to an Int!
```

This isn't possible with a `val` so the above class could be covariant at the declaration site if `item` were a `val`.

Comment: thanks but i had trouble to find an example where it can be a problem if a methods get parameter type as argument, it the parameter type serve as a val property in the Container class.